# Different values when ANDING and assigned uints to a char array in C++ and C#

Tags: c#, c++

I have a very simple problem that is giving me a really big headache in that I am port a bit of code from C++ into C# and for a very simple operation I am getting totally different results:-

C++

```
char OutBuff[25];       
int i;
unsigned int SumCheck = 46840;

OutBuff[i++] = SumCheck & 0xFF; //these 2 ANDED make 248
```

The value written to the char array is -8

C#

```
char[] OutBuff = new char[25]; 
int i;
uint SumCheck = 46840;
OutBuff[i++] = (char)(sumCheck & 0xFF); //these 2 ANDED also make 248
```

The value written to the char array is 248.

Interestingly they are both the same characters, so this may be something to do with the format of a char array in C++ and C# - but ultimately I would be grateful if someone could give me a definitive answer.

Thanks in advance for any help.

David

Comment: Thankyou all for your responses - assumed it was something like this, not sure how I've managed to miss in all my years of software development that a char in C++ and C# are of different lengths - should have been able to work it out by looking at the bit pattern really - but I suppose it's one of those things where you're looking so closely at a problem that you ignore the obvious - lucky there are excellent sites out here for this kind of thing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should be using byte or sbyte instead of char. (char is only to store text chars and the actual binary serialization for char is not the same as in c++.  char allows us to store characters without worrying about character byte width.)

Comment: You still have to worry about character encoding with the `char` data type.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @Eric:  Thanks for the correction.  I modified my answer to reflect it.

Comment: Switched everything to Sbyte and all looks good now. Thankyou.

Answer (score 3):

Its **overflow** in C++, and **no overflow** in C#.

In C#, `char` is **two** byte. In C++, `char` is **one** byte!

So in C#, there is no overflow, and the value is retained. In C++, there is integral overflow.

Change the data type from `char` to `uint16_t` or `unsigned char` (in C++), you will see same result. Note that `unsigned char` can have a value of `248`, without overflow. It can have value upto `255`, in fact.

Comment: That's the problem... Eugenio gives the answer (but then make an incorrect statement about character encoding).

Comment: OK, but `wchar_t` is not guaranteed to have two bytes. It might just have one. Were you thinking of `char16_t` or `uint16_t` maybe?

Comment: @Kerrek: Yes. You're right. `sizeof(wchar_t)`  is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 1):

A [C# `char` is actually 16 bits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay.aspx), while a C++ `char` is *usually* 8 bits ([a `char` is exactly 8 bits on Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc953fe1.aspx)). So you're actually [overflowing the integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) in the C++ code, but the C# code does not overflow, since it holds more bits, and therefore has a bigger integer range.

Notice that 248 is outside the range of a signed `char` (-128 to 127). That should give you a hint that C#'s `char` might be bigger than 8 bits.

You're probably meant to use [C#'s `sbyte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d86he86x.aspx), (the closest equivalent to Visual C++'s `char`) if you want to preserve the behavior. Although you may want to recheck the code code since there's an overflow occurring in the C++ implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has stated, in C# a char is 16 bits while in C++ it is usually 8 bits.

-8 and 248 in binary both (essentially) look like this:

```
11111000
```

Because a char in C++ is usually 8 bits (which is in fact your case), the result is -8. In C#, the value looks like this:

```
00000000 11111000
```

Which is 16 bits and becomes 248.

Answer (score 0):

[2's complement representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) of -8 is the same as the binary represenation of 248 (unsigned)
So the binary representation is the same in both cases. The c++ is interpreted as an int8 result and in c# it's simply interpreted as a positive integer (int is 32 bit an truncating to 16 by casting to char doesn't affect the sign in this case)

Answer (score 0):

The difference between -8 and 248 is all in how you interpret the data.  They are stored exactly the same (0xF8).  In C++, the default char type is 'signed'.  So, 0xF8 = -8.  If you change the data type to 'unsigned char', it will be interpreted as 248.  VS also has a compiler option to make 'char' default to 'unsigned'.